# Autocomplete on command-line search pattern returns strange symbols of <09> and ^I

Tags: neovim, search, command-line, autocmd

Using Neovim v0.4.3 on a just recently upgraded Linux Mint 19.3.

**Problem Description:**

> After the upgrade, when typing `/` followed by first characters of any word below the cursor, in the buffer, and pressing the `<Tab>`, Neovim return on the command-line a strange `<09>` symbol.

**Expected Behavior:**

> Before the upgrade, when typing `/` followed by first characters of any word below the cursor, in the buffer, and pressing the `<Tab>`, Neovim would gracefully autocomplete the search on the command-line.

**Steps Taken to Remedy**

> 1. Applied same *init.vim* configuration as before upgrade (problem persisted)
> 2. Searched for solution or any hint on google.
> 3. Scanned throw Neovim 'cmdline-completion' manual and tested a number of combinations on 'wildchar', 'wildmenu' and 'wildmode'.
> 4. Created a minimal *init.vim* and tested above behavior on stripped '.vimrc' with no plugins and minimal configuration:

```
     set nocompatible
     filetype plugin indent on
     syntax on
     set hidden
```

> Tested above behavior after opening Nvim:
>   `$ nvim -u $HOME/.config/nvim/mini.vim`
>
> Now, when typing / followed by first characters of any word below the cursor, in the buffer, and pressing the `<Tab>`, Neovim returns on command-line a strange `^I` symbol.

Kindly, assist in solving this problem. Your solution, idea, hint, or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex code of `<tab>` is `0x09` and is equivalent to `<C-i>` (displayed as `^I`).

To insert the word under the cursor in the command line, you need `<C-r><C-w>`.

So you are missing a mapping from `<tab>` to `<C-r><C-w>`:

```
cnoremap <tab> <C-r><C-w>
```